# How to avoid nested elements when inserting inside the TinyMCE rich text editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I use the code below to add a merge field into the [TinyMCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) rich text editor:

```javascript
var wc = `<em class="${t} shortcode" data-unique-id="${rId}" data-control="merge-field">[[${text}]]</em>`;
tinymce.get('document-template').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, wc);
```

But when the elements are getting inserted, they all get nested within the previously inserted element like this:

```html
<em class="Standard shortcode"
    data-unique-id="ATK8N"
    data-control="merge-field">[[Legal Full Name]]<em class="Standard shortcode"
        data-unique-id="A8TI8"
        data-control="merge-field">[[ Company Address Country]]<em class="DocumentSender shortcode"
            data-unique-id="HCFMG"
            data-control="merge-field">[[ Last Name]]</em>
    </em>
</em>
```

I want to avoid nesting at all times and ensure that there is never a case when one em element is nested in another, they should always be standalone like this:

```html
<em class="Standard shortcode" data-unique-id="ATK8N" data-control="merge-field">[[Legal Full Name]]</em>
<em class="Standard shortcode" data-unique-id="A8TI8" data-control="merge-field">[[ Company Address Country]]</em>
<em class="DocumentSender shortcode" data-unique-id="HCFMG" data-control="merge-field">[[ Last Name]]</em>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: As far as I remember, the ```execCommand('mceInsertContent', ...)``` command behaviour is for TinyMCE to intelligently treat the inserted content as a fragment. Thus, TinyMCE automatically nests new content within the previous element. You could try the ```selection.setContent``` instead, see following: ```tinymce.get('document-template').selection.setContent(wc);```. This inserts as fresh insertion of HTML. If that does not work, there is ```mceInsertRawHTML``` option: ```tinymce.get('document-template').execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, wc);``` but this could add bad <script> elements.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `array` and iterate over it to get the desired result as  :

```
var mergeFields = [
  {
    class: "Standard shortcode",
    uniqueId: "ATK8N",
    control: "merge-field",
    text: "[[Legal Full Name]]"
  },
  {
    class: "Standard shortcode",
    uniqueId: "A8TI8",
    control: "merge-field",
    text: "[[Company Address Country]]"
  },
  {
    class: "DocumentSender shortcode",
    uniqueId: "HCFMG",
    control: "merge-field",
    text: "[[Last Name]]"
  }
];

mergeFields.forEach(function(field) {
  var wc = `<em class="${field.class}" data-unique-id="${field.uniqueId}" data-control="${field.control}">${field.text}</em>`;
  tinymce.get('document-template').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, wc);
});
```